# How to set scroll in web browser control in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to set the position of the webpage in a web browser control. the application size is smaller than the webpage. I want to set it in the middle of it.
Edit: I think I failed to explain my problem properly,
see these scroll bars of the webviewer control? I wanted to move them programmatically.
[Scroll bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWuEA.png)

Comment: Hello DarkDuck. This is not a specific programming question. Please do your own research first. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You might want to learn about BootStrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets you most of the way there

Note that the main form is set `AutoSize = true` and `AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink`

When the `html` document is navigated to, a check is made is to see if either scrollbar is present. If either scrollbar is present, the size of the `webbrowser` is set to the scroll rectangle, i.e., the web browser will grow to the minimum size needed to display the webpage. Since main form is `AutoSize`, it will resize to fit the `webbrowser`

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //comment out one of these for testing

            webBrowser1.Navigate(@"C:\foo\minimumWebPage.htm");
            //webBrowser1.Navigate(@"C:\foo\bigWebPage.htm");
        }

        private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsHorizontalScrollbarPresent() || IsVerticalScrollbarPresent())
            {
                webBrowser1.Size = new Size(webBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width, webBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height);
            }
        }

        public bool IsHorizontalScrollbarPresent()
        {
            return webBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width > webBrowser1.Document.Window.Size.Width;
        }

        public bool IsVerticalScrollbarPresent()
        {
            return webBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height > webBrowser1.Document.Window.Size.Height;
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.webBrowser1 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "Go";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button1_Click);
            // 
            // webBrowser1
            // 
            this.webBrowser1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(11, 66);
            this.webBrowser1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10);
            this.webBrowser1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
            this.webBrowser1.Name = "webBrowser1";
            this.webBrowser1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(330, 138);
            this.webBrowser1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.AutoSize = true;
            this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(475, 222);
            this.Controls.Add(this.webBrowser1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Show Get-NetConnectionProfile Output";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1;
    }
}
```

**Output for minimum html file

[image]

**Output for big html file

[image]